# Puppeteer/JQuery: selectors doesn't work in scrolling script

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping, jquery-selectors, puppeteer

I am trying to create a basic script to just scroll down to the bottom of the [hacker news](https://news.ycombinator.com/news) site. The scrolling implementation was taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51529332/puppeteer-scroll-down-until-you-cant-anymore) so question (2nd answer by kimbaudi, 1st method).

The implementation works by constantly measuring the `.length` of a list of elements (as provided by a `selector`) while scrolling, to figure out if the browser has successfully scrolled to the bottom of said list of elements.

For my `selector`, I chose the HTML element housing each article on hacker news, `tr.athing`, with the intent of scrolling down to the bottom-most article link. Instead, even though `tr.athing` as a `selector` is printable (as seen in the code below), I get the following error:

`Error: Error: failed to find element matching selector "tr.athing:last-child"`

What is going wrong?

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const link = 'https://news.ycombinator.com/';

// 2 functions used in scrolling
async function getCount(page) {
  await console.log(page.$$eval("tr.athing", a => a.length));
  return await page.$$eval("tr.athing", a => a.length);
}

async function scrollDown(page) {
  await page.$eval("tr.athing:last-child", e => {
    e.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'end', inline: 'end' });
  });
}


// puppeteer usage as normal
puppeteer.launch({ headless: false }).then(async browser => {

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  const navigationPromise = page.waitForNavigation();
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1500, height: 800 });

  // Loading page
  await page.goto(link);
  await navigationPromise;
  await page.waitFor(1000);

  // Using cheerio to inject jquery into page.
  const html = await page.content();
  const $ = await cheerio.load(html);

  // This works
  var selection = $('tr.athing').text();

  await console.log('\n');
  await console.log(selection);
  await console.log('\n');

  // Error, this does not work for some reason;
  // scrolling code starts here.
  const delay = 10000;
  let preCount = 0;
  let postCount = 0;

  do {
    preCount = getCount(page);
    scrollDown(page);
   page.waitFor(delay);
    postCount = getCount(page);
  } while (postCount > preCount);
      page.waitFor(delay);


//  await browser.close();

})
```

Answer (score 0):

The [last-child](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp) selector won't get you the last element but the last element of its parent.

> The :last-child selector matches every element that is the last child of its parent.

You could do something like this instead:

```js
async function scrollDown(page) {
  await page.$$eval("tr.athing", els => {
    els[els.length -1].scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'end', inline: 'end' });
  });
}
```

Also notice that you have many missing awaits in your code

```js
do {
    preCount = await getCount(page);
    await scrollDown(page);
    await page.waitFor(delay);
    postCount = await getCount(page);
} while (postCount > preCount);
    await page.waitFor(delay);
```

Comment: Thanks for at least clearing up my understanding of that method, that `last-child` takes the `last` sibling, essentially, hardkoded! However, having inputted your suggestions, I now get a different error in my app (the previous one assumedly having been vanquished): `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of undefined`.
Would you also help me with this one?

Comment: @Coolio2654 maybe in the first loop you have no records yet. You could add some `if(els.length)` before calling scrollIntoView.

Comment: Ok, I solved the error that was in my code before, and now it runs! Thank you very much. Could you tell me why using `:last-child` originally was not working? It seems to me that should have still caused a scroll event to occur, even if it wasn't to the last instance of the selector (as originally intended), but to some other element.

Comment: It doesn't work because there are not TR with a class `athing` which is the `last-child` if its parent. If you see the HTML the last child of the parent (a TBODY) is a TR with no class. If the answer helped you an upvote will be appreciated :)