# Trouble modifying an object within page.evaluate in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am creating a Twitter scraper as a project. Tweets are rendered in the DOM as you scroll down so I want to use Puppeteer to scroll, extract data and save it into a predefined object, then continue scrolling. The problem is that the script is not actually modifying the object provided and I am left with an empty object.

The for loop to extract data works when called outside the scrolling function (i.e. I can extract the first tweets rendered in the page). The scrolling function itself works, I got it from [Puppeteer - scroll down until you can't anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51529332/puppeteer-scroll-down-until-you-cant-anymore) .

For testing purposes I set the scrolling function to only scroll 20 times (it is otherwise designed to scroll until it can't scroll anymore). Here is my code:

```
app.get('/scrape', async (req, res) => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)
    await page.goto(`https://twitter.com/${req.query.url}`);
    await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)
    let obj = {}
    await autoScroll(page, obj)
    async function autoScroll(page, obj) {
        await page.evaluate(async (obj) => {
            await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                var totalHeight = 0;
                var distance = 400;
                var count = 0
                var timer = setInterval(() => {
                    var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
                    window.scrollBy(0, distance);
                    totalHeight += distance;
                    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                        let id, date, text
                        try {
                            id = document.body.childNodes[7].childNodes[3].childNodes[1].childNodes[5].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].childNodes[3].childNodes[1].childNodes[3].childNodes[7].childNodes[1].childNodes[3].childNodes[1].childNodes[i].childNodes[1].getAttribute('data-tweet-id')
                            date = document.body.childNodes[7].childNodes[3].childNodes[1].childNodes[5].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].childNodes[3].childNodes[1].childNodes[3].childNodes[7].childNodes[1].childNodes[3].childNodes[1].childNodes[i].childNodes[1].childNodes[3].childNodes[1].childNodes[3].childNodes[1].getAttribute('title')
                            text = document.body.childNodes[7].childNodes[3].childNodes[1].childNodes[5].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].childNodes[3].childNodes[1].childNodes[3].childNodes[7].childNodes[1].childNodes[3].childNodes[1].childNodes[i].childNodes[1].childNodes[3].childNodes[3].childNodes[1].innerHTML
                            obj[id] = { date: date, text: text }
                            console.log(i)
                        } catch (err) { continue }
                    }
                    count++
                    //if(totalHeight >= scrollHeight){
                    if (count === 20) {
                        clearInterval(timer);
                        resolve();
                    }
                }, 400);
            });
        }, obj);
    }
    res.send(obj)
    await browser.close();
})
```

The request sends an empty object every time. I don't receive any error messages or console logs; if they are there, I can't see them because they are executed in the context of the headless Chrome browser than Puppeteer generates.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you use a transpiler like babel for your node code?

Comment: Not for this file, no. My front end is React JSX so I am transpiling that with babel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments you pass to `page.evaluate` will be JSON-serialized and transferred to the page context.

The properties you assign to `obj` in your `page.evaluate()` function will only be present in the page context, not in the script where you called `page.evaluate`.

You can work around this by returning the `obj` object from the function instead of passing it as parameter:

```
let obj = await page.evaluate(async() => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
      let obj = {};
      // ...
      // set something on obj
      obj['foo'] = 'bar';

      // resolve with the obj
      resolve(obj);
      // ...
  });
});
```

Integrated in your code snippet:

```js
app.get('/scrape', async (req, res) => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)
    await page.goto(`https://twitter.com/${req.query.url}`);
    await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)
    let obj = await autoScroll(page);
    async function autoScroll(page) {
        return page.evaluate(async () => {
            let obj = {};
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                var totalHeight = 0;
                var distance = 400;
                var count = 0
                var timer = setInterval(() => {
                    var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
                    window.scrollBy(0, distance);
                    totalHeight += distance;
                    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                        let id, date, text
                        try {
                            id = document.body.childNodes[7].childNodes[3].childNodes[1].childNodes[5].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].childNodes[3].childNodes[1].childNodes[3].childNodes[7].childNodes[1].childNodes[3].childNodes[1].childNodes[i].childNodes[1].getAttribute('data-tweet-id')
                            date = document.body.childNodes[7].childNodes[3].childNodes[1].childNodes[5].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].childNodes[3].childNodes[1].childNodes[3].childNodes[7].childNodes[1].childNodes[3].childNodes[1].childNodes[i].childNodes[1].childNodes[3].childNodes[1].childNodes[3].childNodes[1].getAttribute('title')
                            text = document.body.childNodes[7].childNodes[3].childNodes[1].childNodes[5].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].childNodes[3].childNodes[1].childNodes[3].childNodes[7].childNodes[1].childNodes[3].childNodes[1].childNodes[i].childNodes[1].childNodes[3].childNodes[3].childNodes[1].innerHTML
                            obj[id] = { date: date, text: text }
                            console.log(i)
                        } catch (err) { continue }
                    }
                    count++
                    //if(totalHeight >= scrollHeight){
                    if (count === 20) {
                        clearInterval(timer);
                        resolve(obj);
                    }
                }, 400);
            });
        });
    }
    res.send(obj)
    await browser.close();
})
```

If you're using a transpiler like babel you might need to pass the function as a string to `page.evaluate`, e.g.:

```
await page.evaluate(`async() => {
  return Promise.resolve(42);
}`);
```

(puppeteer will call `.toString()` on your function to get the source, which might contain [references to helpers used by babel](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/3312), which aren't present in the page context)

Edit:
To debug your selectors you can try to launch puppeteer in [non-headless mode](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer#default-runtime-settings).
That way you get a real browser window where you can access the dev console.
e.g.:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
```

Comment: Thank you, I am not using babel to transpile this file. I implemented your code and it returned undefined. I added another return statement as "return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {" and got an empty object as my result.

Comment: After further testing I tried adding obj.a = 1 to my for loop and it did return that, so I think your code is working and it is my try/catch that is failing to return any data. Should I be using id = await page.evaluate(i => document.body.childNode[7]... , i) inside another evaluate function? I am not sure where the problem in my logic is here.

Comment: @NickP you're correct i forgot to add the return, fixed it. You could try removing the try / catch and see what errors you are getting. Probably one of your `.childNodes[]` returns null because the element is not there. You can also use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) or `document.querySelectorAll` if you can target the node you want with css selectors

Comment: I tried making my setInterval async, passing  page into my evaluate function properly, and using the "id = await page.evaluate(i => document.body.childNode[7]... , i)" format instead. I got a circular JSON error. As to your comment, unfortunately there are no selectors to target. The nested childNodes were working when I didn't have them wrapped within the scroll function, so I'm not sure. I will keep playing with it. Sadly I cannot see the specific errors within my evaluate function since they show up in the invisible headless Chrome instance which makes debugging especially tough.

Comment: @NickP you can't pass the `page` into evaluate. All arguments you pass to `evaluate` must be either JSON serializable (plain objects or primitives) or JSHandles (a handle referring to an object in the page)

Comment: @NickP you could try launching puppeteer in non-headless mode, that way you can see the logs within the evaluate function in the dev console of the window & pause on exceptions to see where your code is failing