# Puppeteer - simulate scroll down

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I have seen that there are functions like `page.mouse.down()` but it does nothing.
Do you know any way to scroll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `page.mouse.down()` is used to simulate a mouse click, not the scroll. That's why it doesn't do what you want to.

You may have to take a look at the [window.scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) or [window.scrollBy](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollBy) function to be used inside the `page.evaluate(...)` scope (in which the window variable is available). You'll then be able to scroll the page by some given `distance`. Please see the following topic in which the answer has already been given : [Puppeteer - scroll down until you can't anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51529332/puppeteer-scroll-down-until-you-cant-anymore)

Answer (score 2):

I made it work by `await page.keyboard.press("PageDown");`

Comment: It doesn't work on mobile?

Comment: This is what I've been looking for. Super simple one-liner that does the job, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After page load execute regular JS to scroll to some element:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollBy

If you have some specific DOM element you want to scroll to, you will need it's offset from top.

e.g.:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  const element = document.getElementById('some-id');
  const y = element.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset;
  window.scrollTo({top: y});        
});
```

Of course you can use any selector, not only by id. But make sure to select single DOM element to use `getBoundingClientRect()`