# Fetching data with puppeteer

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, browser, puppeteer, headless

I try to fetch all link of images from 1st search page using Puppeteer but I only get 6 links from total 40. Here is my code :

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

puppeteer.launch({ headless: true }).then(async browser => {
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://shopee.vn/search?keyword=iphone%20xs' , {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});

  const links = await page.evaluate( () => {

    let products_result = document.getElementsByClassName("_1T9dHf _3XaILN");

    let images = [];

    for(let i=0; i<products_result.length; i++){
      images[i] = products_result[i].src;
    }

    return images;

  });

  for(let i=0; i<links.length;i++){
  console.log('Links of ' + i +' images : ',links[i]);
  }
  await browser.close();
});
```

What should I fix to get total 40 links from 1st search page ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the site in question is doing some lazy loading of images and / or some on-demand DOM manipulation.

So, we'll try scrolling down the page, using an adaptation of this excellent answer:

[Puppeteer - scroll down until you can't anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51529332/puppeteer-scroll-down-until-you-cant-anymore/53527984#53527984).

What we also do is to take an image of the page (Open ./page.png in the directory you run the script in!), this can help you see what is loading (or not!)
Code is below:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

// Scroll downwards slowly
async function scroll(page){
    await page.evaluate(async () => {
        await new Promise(resolve => {
            // Adjust as necessary
            const y = 50, speed = 20;
            let heightScrolled = 0;

            setInterval(() => {
                window.scrollBy(0, y);
                heightScrolled += y;
                if (heightScrolled >= document.body.scrollHeight) {
                    resolve();
                }
            }, speed);
        });
    });
}

async function getImages(url) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});

    await page.setViewport({
        width: 1200,
        height: 800
    });

    await scroll(page);

    // Take an image of the page.. see what it looks like!
    await page.screenshot({
        fullPage: true,
        path: `./page.png`
    });

    const links = await page.evaluate( () => {

        let products_result = document.getElementsByClassName("_1T9dHf _3XaILN");
        let images = [];

        for(let i=0; i<products_result.length; i++){
        images[i] = products_result[i].src;
        }
        return images;
    });

    for(let i=0; i<links.length;i++){
        console.log('Links of ' + i +' images : ',links[i]);
    }
    await browser.close();
}

let url = 'https://shopee.vn/search?keyword=iphone%20xs'
getImages(url);
```

Comment: Forgot about scrolling, I just update your code and It works perfect. Thanks Terry so much, you're awesome <3

Comment: Great,  glad to help ! Happy coding!