# Is there a way to indefinitely scroll on spotify using puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, scroll, puppeteer, spotify

I'm new to node.js and puppeteer and I was trying to find a way to scroll to the end of a playlist to scrape song names and artists. I've tried the top answer from this question:
[Puppeteer - scroll down until you can't anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51529332/puppeteer-scroll-down-until-you-cant-anymore)

which worked for a site like google but was ineffective for spotify.
I've tried code like `window.scrollBy()` but I have a hunch that the scrollbar is created from javascript and I can't think of a way to display more of the playlist.

here's an example playlist that lazy loads https://open.spotify.com/playlist/37i9dQZF1DWWQRwui0ExPn

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to node as well but I think with mouse.move you should get something

[mouse wheel options - puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v5.2.1/docs/api.md#mousewheeloptions)

(the code is from the doc)

```
await page.goto('https://mdn.mozillademos.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/wheel_event$samples/Scaling_an_element_via_the_wheel?revision=1587366');

const elem = await page.$('div');
const boundingBox = await elem.boundingBox();
await page.mouse.move(
  boundingBox.x + boundingBox.width / 2,
  boundingBox.y + boundingBox.height / 2
);

await page.mouse.wheel({ deltaY: -100 })
```

Never used it yet but it's definitely worth the try.