# Implementing scroll to bottom in puppeteer sharp

Tags: c#, webautomation, puppeteer-sharp

I am struggling and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.  I am using puppeteer sharp in a .net desktop project.

I want to make to page loaded into puppeteer to scroll to the bottom to deal with some lazy loading, and I have found several articles such as [Puppeteer - scroll down until you can't anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51529332/puppeteer-scroll-down-until-you-cant-anymore) that contain loads of useful info, but for Javascript - I can't work out how to implement this in Puppeteer sharp.

For example I would like to try running this under puppeteer sharp somehow (as I read in the above mentioned article it will do the scroll to bottom) : -

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight);
});
```

The documentation for puppeteer sharp doesnt seem to cover the above.

cyr

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do

```cs
await page.EvaluateExpressionAsync("window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight)");
```

Comment: Hi thankyou for your reply.  Would I put that before or after the page.Goto ?

Comment: Hello again.  Please ignore that last question it works now - it is called after.  Is there a way to capture the URL's from a <nav> that use <button> links?

Comment: @cyrilaldertonmods1946 what do you mean with capture?

Comment: The <nav> menu links are all <button data-id="123xyz"> links, each with an id attribute, that when clicked, redirects to a to a url such as https://example.com/aa/bb//1123344 - what i want to do i capture each URL for each button link when clicked

Comment: Hello again. I realise now I need to use redirect chain, however I am able to see reference in node js for redirect chain but not how to do it in puppeteer sharp. The docs say nothing about supporting it, so is it impossible with puppeteer sharp please? If so how can it be done if possible to tell / share?

Comment: How about this https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp/blob/2196ff46d9b31e75dd8dfddbaeac0c5cabeab9b9/lib/PuppeteerSharp.Tests/NetworkTests/SetRequestInterceptionTests.cs#L312 ?