# Infinite scrolling with puppeteer when scraping

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, infinite-scroll

I have a scraping program that goes to youtube and fetch the img src of every thumbnail. The problem with it is even though the programs navigation to the src url and recording it works youtube has a infinite scrolling feature that hat ensures the client browser only fetches the items once the user scrolled them into view. So to deal with the infinite scrolling I added a function that scroll to the part of the page that can create more content at the bottom and selectors i.e. `document.querySelectorAll('.class_name').length` to check whether more content has been generated but the program still doesn't deal with the infinite scrolling issue. I can't figure out what I missed. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
async function scrape(url) {

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url, {
    timeout: 0
  });
  await page.setViewport({
    width: 1200,
    height: 800
  });

  const delay = 3000;
  let preCount = 0;
  let postCount = 0;
  do {
    preCount = await getCount(page);
    await scrollDown(page);
    await page.waitFor(delay);
    postCount = await getCount(page);
  } while (postCount > preCount);
  await page.waitFor(delay);

  const srcSelector = 'ytd-thumbnail > a > yt-img-shadow > #img'
  const ytSrcData = await page.$$eval(srcSelector, elems => elems.map(el => el.src).join('\n'))

  browser.close();

  console.log({
    ytTextData,
    ytSrcData
  })


}

async function getCount(page) {
  return await page.$$eval('.ytd-rich-item-renderer', a => a.length);
}

async function scrollDown(page) {
  await page.$eval('.ytd-rich-item-renderer:last-child', e => {
    e.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth',
      block: 'end',
      inline: 'end'
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: What YT page is this intended to work on? [Puppeteer - scroll down until you can't anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51529332/puppeteer-scroll-down-until-you-cant-anymore?rq=1) and [Log that bottom scroll has been reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73643527/log-that-bottom-scroll-has-been-reached/73644761#73644761)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of scrolling to a certain element that may or may not exist, just scroll to the bottom of the page.

```
scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
```

Like this...

```
async function scrollDown(page) {
  await page.evaluate(function(){
    scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
  });
}
```

Comment: you mean something like. ```await page.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);```. @I wrestled a bear once.

Comment: @anon20010813 no, you don't need await. scrollTo is synchronous.

Comment: I'm getting error document is not defined.@I wrestled a bear once.

Comment: @anon20010813 - you're calling it in the correct context, right? see my update.