# How to capture shadow root element with puppeteer page.screenshot() method?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

[image: Current output]
I am trying to capture screenshot of webpage using puppeteer **page.screenshot** method. But when I see the output screenshot it misses some part of page which is shadow root element inside html.
How can I
capture shadow root element also with puppeteer screenshot method. I am currently using below code. Example URL is https://www.buybuybaby.com/

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
      'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
      accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9'
    })


await page.goto("https://www.buybuybaby.com/", {    //URL with shadow root element
            waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
            timeout: 160000   
})

await page.setViewport({
    width: 1600,
    height: 20000
  })

await page.screenshot({path: 'screenshot.png'});

await browser.close();
```

Comment: Edited my question with whole code and url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page seems to be lazyloading the links/products, try with this awesome [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53527984/3163418)

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.buybuybaby.com/', { waitUntil: 'load' });
    await page.setViewport({
        width: 1200,
        height: 800
    });

    const element = await page.$("#trendingProductsList"); 

    await autoScroll(page);

    await page.screenshot({
        path: 'yoursite.png',
        fullPage: true
    });

    await browser.close();
})();

async function autoScroll(page) {
    await page.evaluate(async () => {
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var totalHeight = 0;
            var distance = 100;
            var timer = setInterval(() => {
                var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
                window.scrollBy(0, distance);
                totalHeight += distance;

                if (totalHeight >= scrollHeight) {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    resolve();
                }
            }, 100);
        });
    });
}
```

[this is my screenshot](https://flic.kr/p/2myUq5X)

Comment: This isn't working. Shadow root elements still missing inside screenshot.

Comment: I tried the code, added { waitUntil: 'load' } and now it seems to work good again :)

Comment: Tried same code still same result shadow root elements are missing.

Comment: Can you give an example of what is missing?

Comment: I have added output screenshot as you can see it misses footer part.

Comment: I see, updated the code so we get the footer parts.
const element = await page.$("#trendingProductsList");  seems to be key for scraping shadow dom element

Comment: Still missing. Can you share your output screenshot?

Comment: yes, will post it later today here

Comment: May be I got the issue its because of old puppeteer version I am using.

Comment: I am using puppeteer version 5.5.0. Can you help me to solve this for puppteer 5.5.0 version? Thanks.

Comment: Don't sure if 5.5.0 supports the shadow dom/select object by javascript path.
I used 10.4.0 for my answer

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I have resolved the issue with new puppeteer version using your code.